# How to improve sql server query response time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains 60 million records with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.cus_pivot_non_unique_indexes
  (
     SEQ_ID                              BIGINT,
     SRM_CLIENT_ENTITIES_SEQ_ID          BIGINT,
     CUS_ENTITY_DATA_SEQ_ID              BIGINT,
     SRM_CLIENT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTES_SEQ_ID BIGINT,
     ATTRIBUTE_DATETIME                  DATETIME,
     ATTRIBUTE_DECIMAL                   DECIMAL(18, 2),
     ATTRIBUTE_STRING                    NVARCHAR(255),
     ATTRIBUTE_BOOLEAN                   CHAR(1),
     SRM_CLIENTS_SEQ_ID                  BIGINT
  )
```

The table has two indexes.

1. Clustered index with key `SEQ_ID`
2. Non unique non clustered index : I've following four composite indexes

   a. `SRM_CLIENTS_SEQ_ID, SRM_CLIENT_ENTITIES_SEQ_ID, SRM_CLIENT_ENTITY_ATTRIBTUES_SEQ_ID, ATTRIBUTE_DATETIME`

   b. `SRM_CLIENTS_SEQ_ID, SRM_CLIENT_ENTITIES_SEQ_ID,  SRM_CLIENT_ENTITY_ATTRIBTUES_SEQ_ID, ATTRIBUTE_DECIMAL`

   c. `SRM_CLIENTS_SEQ_ID, SRM_CLIENT_ENTITIES_SEQ_ID,  SRM_CLIENT_ENTITY_ATTRIBTUES_SEQ_ID, ATTRIBUTE_STRING`

   d. `SRM_CLIENTS_SEQ_ID, SRM_CLIENT_ENTITIES_SEQ_ID,  SRM_CLIENT_ENTITY_ATTRIBTUES_SEQ_ID, ATTRIBUTE_BOOLEAN`

The problem is that when I execute a simple query over this table it does not return the results in an acceptable time.

**Query:**

```
SELECT CUS_ENTITY_DATA_SEQ_ID  
FROM   dbo.cus_pivot_non_unique_indexes 
WHERE  srm_client_entity_attributes_seq_id = 51986 
       AND attribute_decimal = 4150196
```

**Execution Time** : 2 seconds

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that your non clustered index doesn't appear to help your query. You are also returning all columns, so even if your index did help you would still need to do a key lookup on the clustered index. Do you really need to select all columns? If you only need a few you can create the index Martin has suggested and have the columns you need as non key columns.

Comment: For future questions please just supply the `CREATE TABLE` it is easier to parse than a bullet list of column names and datatypes. Also your index descriptions are missing some information (you don't mention if the first index is unique and the second one was also stated as "clustered" I've edited to say "nonclustered")

Comment: Well I see you also have added info about yet more indexes. None of them have leading column of `SRM_CLIENT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTES_SEQ_ID` or `ATTRIBUTE_DECIMAL` so they won't help either.

Comment: Do you *really* need all four of those very similar indexes anyway though? How selective is `SRM_CLIENTS_SEQ_ID, SRM_CLIENT_ENTITIES_SEQ_ID, SRM_CLIENT_ENTITY_ATTRIBTUES_SEQ_ID` on its own?

Comment: Yes i need all these four indexes...If I need to search for DateTime so I have index for it i.e ATTRIBUTE_DATETIME. similarly for String, Boolean and decimal.

Comment: Every index has a cost when it comes to inserts/updates/deletes. I don't know your data and selectivities but rather suspect that you could get away with just having one on the first three columns that all four of those queries could still make good use of.

Answer (score 7):

The indexes you have aren't useful for this query.

You need one with leading columns `SRM_CLIENT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTES_SEQ_ID, ATTRIBUTE_DECIMAL` (in either order) to get a seek.

Possibly you might want to `INCLUDE` the other table columns to make the index covering and avoid lookups. This depends on the selectivity of the predicate and your overall workload balance.

Comment: +1 for understanding only .. i was trying to understand what OP is asking